# Mongo crash on VPS centos8.3

Tags: centos, mongodb

I use centos 8.3 on my VPS. ( 1gb ram 1cpu ) Digital ocean service. I am not sure which case is it but maybe mem usage. Error begin to be active after i run ue4 dedicated server how use normal 3% cpu and
Data from top :

```
top - 16:15:38 up 39 days, 23:16,  2 users,  load average: 0.02, 0.05, 0.01
Tasks: 175 total,   2 running, 164 sleeping,   5 stopped,   4 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1.7 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 97.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.3 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :    807.5 total,     75.6 free,    551.8 used,    180.0 buff/cache
MiB Swap:      0.0 total,      0.0 free,      0.0 used.     87.3 avail Mem

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 502469 unreal    20   0  298248  42124    964 S   1.7   5.1 468:57.65 BrmServer-Linux
 687287 root      20   0  275172   4528   3844 R   0.7   0.5   0:00.10 top
 687189 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:00.84 kworker/0:1-events
      1 root      20   0  255756   8208   3064 S   0.0   1.0  28:52.35 systemd
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.59 kthreadd
      3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_gp
```

Error log:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-19T21:19:02.127+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":20499,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"serverStatus was very slow","attr":{"timeStats":{"after basic":173,"after asserts":599,"after connections":891,"after electionMetrics":1794,"after extra_info":2341,"after flowControl":2656,"after freeMonitoring":3007,"after globalLock":3428,"after locks":3723,"after logicalSessionRecordCache":3869,"after mirroredReads":3904,"after network":3990,"after opLatencies":4047,"after opReadConcernCounters":4127,"after opcounters":4189,"after opcountersRepl":4189,"after oplogTruncation":4335,"after repl":4521,"after security":4662,"after storageEngine":4818,"after tcmalloc":4978,"after trafficRecording":5017,"after transactions":5055,"after transportSecurity":5088,"after twoPhaseCommitCoordinator":5134,"after wiredTiger":6342,"at end":6820}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-19T21:19:02.452+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn48","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:47742","connectionId":48,"connectionCount":2}}
[1]+  Killed                  mongod --dbpath data --bind_ip localhost
Killed
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Give it enough memory.

Comment: Yes i will take another droplet with 1gb 1cpu . I am not sure which is better choose to move it `ue4 server ` or `mongo` on new clear server. If i move mongo than i need to allow remote connection which is bad idea . I am already feel  brutal force in that case.